# React - Trying to Changing <img> src attribute

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change the src attribute of an  element after an AJAX call to a database. I have a default image url defined in `getDefaultProps()`, but after the AJAX call the image doesn't change.

`PictureWidget` is a child component of a `Section` component that controls the state (it also passes dataSource and dataSourceParams to `PictureWidget`). I'm not sure if I can use a local state for `PictureWidget` so I'm trying to do it through props.

This is my code:

```
var PictureWidget = React.createClass({

getDefaultProps: function() {
  return {
    url: 'https://d2o57arp16h0eu.cloudfront.net/echo/img/no_image_available.png'
  }
},

componentDidMount: function() {
  this.componentDidUpdate();
},

componentDidUpdate: function() {

  // Grab img URL from DB
  var postData = {
    dataSource: this.props.params.dataSource,
    dataSourceParams: this.props.dataSourceParams
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajax_endpoint,
    cache: false,
    data: postData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.data.length > 0) {
        this.updateImage(response.data[0][0]);
      }
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(response) {
      this.render();
    }
  });

},

updateImage: function(url) {
  console.log("Updating props.url with " + url);
  this.props.url = url;
  this.render();
},

render: function(imageURL) {
  console.log("Rendering img " + this.props.url);

  return React.createElement('div', {className: ' pure-u-' + this.props.columns},
    React.createElement('div', {className: 'picture-widget'},
      React.createElement('img', {src: this.props.url})
    )
  )
}
});
```

And this is my console log (forgive me for the poor formatting, still new to Overflow):

```
Rendering img https://d2o57arp16h0eu.cloudfront.net/echo/img/no_image_available.png
Updating props.url with http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/animalcrossing/images/4/49/Tumblr_lvrcmvCpsS1qbeyouo1_500.jpg/revision/latest
Rendering img http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/animalcrossing/images/4/49/Tumblr_lvrcmvCpsS1qbeyouo1_500.jpg/revision/latest
```

The initial `render()` grabs the default URL, but after the AJAX call `this.props.url` does get updated to the new value, so I would suspect `React.createElement('img', {src: this.props.url})` is the trouble maker. Can I not update the src attribute this way?

Comment: You should never mutate `this.props`, that should only be set by the rendering parent. Use `this.state` instead, and remove the ajax call from the `componentDidUpdate` method, move it to `componentDidMount` instead perhaps?

Comment: @daRealDodo I'm getting the same issue with an audio element. Any chance you can share how you fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

This is what state is for. Try using `getInitialState` instead of `getDefaultProps` and bind `url` to `this.state` using `setState()`.

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    url: 'https://d2o57arp16h0eu.cloudfront.net/echo/img/no_image_available.png'
  };
},

updateImage: function(url) {
  console.log("Updating state.url with " + url);
  this.setState({ url: url });
}
```

Comment: The state is controlled by a higher-level component (Section component for the entire page). I want the widget to refresh whenever Section gets updated (I probably should have added this to the question). I tried making a local state, but then I get infinite update loops: AJAX call -> update state -> componentDidUpdate() -> AJAX call -> ...

Comment: Can you use [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) to determine whether or not you should trigger a `componentDidUpdate` and prevent the loop?

Comment: I've just tried what you suggested with `shouldComponentUpdate`, `console.log("Rendering image " + this.state.url);` outputs the new image URL, `React.createElement('img', {src: this.state.url})` now uses state - the image still stays the same.

Comment: Update: `this.state.url` does appear to work, but the rendering seems to be one image late. If I first select product id 1900, no_image_available.png is show, then I select product 1905, product 1900 is show, then product 1912 - product 1905 is shown...

Comment: That's odd... Any chance it's an issue with the logic in `shouldComponentUpdate`?